# RSpec: Accessing a `let` definition from within a block in an example

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have basically this setting in an RSpec test:

```
RSpec.describe Something do
  describe '#something' do
    let(:my_var) { 'some data' }
    let(:my_object) { MyObject.new }
    it 'example' do
      my_object.instance_eval { @my_inst_var = my_var } # ERROR here
    end
  end
end
```

This results in

*NameError: undefined local variable or method `myvar' for #MyObject:0x5d14e99e*

I understand, that in the execution context of `my_object` Ruby does not know how to deal with the "magic" of the `let` construct in RSpec. I am aware that I could us "normal variables" here instead of `let`, and I also can do (and this is how I am solving the problem at the moment):

```
    # This works of course
    it 'example' do
      mv = my_var # Forces the let(:my_var) to be evaluated
      my_object.instance_eval { @my_inst_var = mv }
    end
```

Question: Is there a better way to do it, assuming that I do want to use `let` and `instance_eval within the example?

Comment: "I understand, that in the execution context of my_object Ruby does not know how to deal with the "magic" of the let construct in RSpec." – There is no magic. `let(:foo)` simply defines a method named `foo`, nothing more. The *whole point* of `instance_eval` is to change `self` so that methods are looked up somewhere else, so obviously, `foo` does not exist. That is one of the *many* reasons why even communities who used it heavily in the past (e.g. Rails) have all but banned its usage: because things that *look* like they should be in scope, aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/BasicObject.html#instance_exec-method) instead – it allows you to pass arguments into the block's scope:

```
my_object.instance_exec(my_var) { |v| @my_inst_var = v }
```

Alternatively, you could set the instance variable via [`instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Object.html#instance_variable_set-method):

```
my_object.instance_variable_set(:@my_inst_var, my_var)
```

Although both of the above work, altering the object's state that way can lead to brittle tests. You should consider changing the object so it becomes easier to test. (add a setter or pass the value upon initialization)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. Using instance_eval isn't high on my list.
If an attr_accessor would make sense you should go that way for sure:

```rb
class Something
  attr_accessor :my_inst_var
end

it 'example' do
  my_object.my_inst_var = my_var
end
```

If you don't want to pollute your objects public methods I would consider the following option much cleaner than instance_eval.

```rb
it 'example' do
  my_object.instance_variable_set :@my_instance_var, my_var
end
```

Comment: I don't want to turn my `attr_reader` into an `attr_accessor` just to make writing the test cases easier, but using `instance_variable_set` is fine for my concrete case. I will accept your answer in a few days, unless someone comes up with a more general solution until then.

Comment: @user1934428 testability > encapsulation